# Не работает лампочка и вибрация при создании уведомления на Android

Tags: java, android, push-уведомления, уведомления

Использую **Java** для создания приложения и мне нужно показать уведомление, но чтобы оно появилось с вибрацией и с мигающим огоньком на телефоне. Вот код, который я сейчас использую в методе **onCreate()** сервиса:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String channelId = "my_channel123";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "test", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "my_channel123")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.fin)
                .setContentTitle("Заголовок")
                .setContentText("Текст")
                .setLights(Color.BLUE, 1000, 1000)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 250, 250, 250})
                .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        @SuppressLint("UnspecifiedImmutableFlag") PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        Notification notification1 = builder.build();
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification1);
```

Вот разрешения в Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

По идеи, код должен работать, но на моём телефоне просто появляется уведомление. Без вибрации, без огонька, но благо со звуком. И уведомление не появляется на экране блокировки. Все разрешения для самого приложения в телефоне есть, он может постить уведомления и я не ставил режим "Не беспокоить".
На моём телефоне стоит Android 10, а марка Honor 10 Lite.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вибрация, звук и свет задаются в канале (у вас не хватает setVibrationPattern) То, что огни не включаются у вас в телефоне, возможно их надо включить в настройках... То же про экран блокировки. Проверьте на эмуляторе сначала, хонор может вести себя не стандартно...

Comment: Понял, спасибо огромное!